# Xcode 6.1 signing certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have updated my Max with XCode 6.1 and it seems that the signing was quite changed here.

When I was archiving my app beofre 6.1 , I was asked which provision I want to use on my app. Today doesn't matter what you are state on your configuration, it allways choose a certificate named with XC : at the beginning.

Any idea how can I control the provision just like old versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Click the Export button to get various deployment options

[image: Choices during archive]

[image: Deployment options]

Comment: Additional, you need set correct sertificate and provision profile in build settings. Some times wrong provision in build settings makes build generation failed.